# Create new column with binary data based on several columns

Tags: r, binary-data

I have a dataframe in which I want to create a new column with 0/1 (which would represent absence/presence of a species) based on the records in previous columns. I've been trying this:

```
update_cat$bobpresent <- NA #creating the new column

x <- c("update_cat$bob1999", "update_cat$bob2000", "update_cat$bob2001","update_cat$bob2002", "update_cat$bob2003", "update_cat$bob2004", "update_cat$bob2005", "update_cat$bob2006","update_cat$bob2007", "update_cat$bob2008", "update_cat$bob2009") #these are the names of the columns I want the new column to base its results in

bobpresent <- function(x){
  if(x==NA)
    return(0)
  else
    return(1)
} # if all the previous columns are NA then the new column should be 0, otherwise it should be 1
```

update_cat$bobpresence <- sapply(update_cat$bobpresent, bobpresent) #apply the function to the new column

Everything is going fina until the last string where I'm getting this error:

```
Error in if (x == NA) return(0) else return(1) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Can somebody please advise me?
Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Which language is this? R?

Comment: try maybe `update_cat$bobpresent <- ifelse(all(is.na(update_cat[,x])), 1, 0)` where x is only the column name `c("bob1999", "bob2000", "bob2001").....

Answer (score 3):

By definition all operations on `NA` will yield `NA`, therefore `x == NA` *always* evaluates to `NA`. If you want to check if a value is `NA`, you must use the `is.na` function, for example:

```
> NA == NA
[1] NA
> is.na(NA)
[1] TRUE
```

The function you pass to `sapply` expects TRUE or FALSE as return values but it gets NA instead, hence the error message. You can fix that by rewriting your function like this:

```
bobpresent <- function(x) { ifelse(is.na(x), 0, 1) }
```

In any case, based on your original post I don't understand what you're trying to do. This change only fixes the error you get with `sapply`, but fixing the logic of your program is a different matter, and there is not enough information in your post.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions. None of them work though. It successfully converts everything in 0 without distinguishing the columns with other data (like 1,2 - these are number of animals captured). Any idea what's happening?

Comment: You need to give us a small sample of your data so we know what sort of values (and their class) are in each column.  Also, your function doesn't refer to the outside variable `x` but rather to the variable you've named in your `sapply` call.  My guess is you want to do something else.  Can you write out pseudocode in some loop so we know what should be happening?