# Create new column with binary data or presence/absence data in R

Tags: r, if-statement, binary-data

The answer to the following question has been addressed more simply than this answer: [Create new column with binary data based on several columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222438/create-new-column-with-binary-data-based-on-several-columns)

I am trying to create a new column of binary data (presence/absence data) based on another column in **R**.

I want "Species_code" rows with the number 101 to produce a 1 in the new "Presence_absence" column; everything else should produce a 0.

Here is what I want the new Presence_absence column to look like:

```
Species_code       Presence_absence
101                1
103                0
101                1
99                 0
101                1
```

Comment: Can you link the previous reply that didn't make sense?

Comment: The previous question was linked.  Since my question is somewhat duplicated, can I delete it once I receive follow-up answers to my further questions below?  I think it would be important to put Presence/Absence in the title of the other Question, however.  Presence and absence data is often used in R, in Biology.

Comment: @ResearcherUsingR did you check the answer below? Is it not sufficient? If it's not, please post a comment below it clarifying what you expected.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ifelse`:

```
> df <- data.frame(Species_code = c(101, 103,101,99,101)) # your data
> df$Presence_absence <- ifelse(df$Species_code==101, 1, 0) # this does the trick
> df
  Species_code Presence_absence
1          101                1
2          103                0
3          101                1
4           99                0
5          101                1
```

Comment: unless `Species_code` happens to be a factor ... you could be defensive via `df$Presence_absence <- ifelse(as.character(df$Species_code)=="101",1,0)`.  Note you could use `as.numeric()` to be more compact if you wanted.

Comment: @BenBolker you are absolutely right.